# Can' t print position of element in an array after heapify-up C++

Tags: c++, heap

Can someone help me with the code in c++ below?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int PARENT(int i)
{
   return (i/2);
}

int Heapify_up(int arra[], int i)
{
   int j,k;
   if (i>1){
     j = PARENT(i);
     if (arra[i]<arra[j]){
        k=arra[i];
        arra[i]=arra[j];
        arra[j]=k;
        Heapify_up(arra, j);
     }
   }
 return j;
}


int main()
{

 int array3[15];
 int i,p,array_length;

 ifstream inputFile1("Heapfile.txt");

 if (inputFile1.good()){

    int current_number = 0;
    i=1;
    while (inputFile1>> current_number)
        array3[i++] = current_number;

    inputFile1.close();
}
array_length = i;

cout<<"Please, enter an integer: ";
cin>>p;
array3[array_length+1]=p;
int pos=Heapify_up(array3, array_length+1);

 for (i=1; i<15; i++){
    cout<<array3[i]<<"  ";
 }
 cout<<"The position is "<<pos;
}
```

Let me explain you that  have an array in a txt file. After i insert a random integer and with the heapify-up algorith I'm sorting this random number to the array. I want to print the new sorted array(I' have done that) and the new position of the random element that i have entered. Any idea?

thanks in advance!
P.S. I am new here and i find it somehow difficult to post my code correctly... still learning! XD

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are multiple problems with your code.

- You make no effort to ensure you don't blow past the size of your
  static array.
- You skip a spot in the array when appending your    manually-added
  value
- Your array length is wrong
- You aren't initializing your variables

Let's start with the last one. Please do something like this:

```
int i{0}, p, array_length;
```

This ensures the i variable is properly initialized to zero.

Next, your code does this:

```
array3[i++] = current_number;
```

This means that at any given time, i is the length of the array.

But later you do this:

```
array_length = i;
array3[array_length+1]=p;
```

Frankly, I would drop variable i entirely and use array_length instead. There is no need for both.

But even without that, you're setting array_length correctly, but then you're inserting to a point AFTER that, so you might start with:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

At this point, i == 5. Input a 6 and have:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6 ]
```

Because you put it at index i+1 not at index i.

At this point, array_length is no longer an accurate length. But you do this:

```
int pos=Heapify_up(array3, array_length+1);
```

So it kind of works.

I don't know why Heapify_up is returning j -- it's just the midpoint of the array. That's not a useful value.

Furthermore, I don't really know what your heapify thing is trying to accomplish.. It certainly isn't a heap-sort. If the middle and end numbers are in sorted order, it doesn't actually do a thing.

This URL might help you with some code:

[Heap sort at Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort/)

As for using a fix-length array -- that's problematic, too, but using std::vector is probably a bit much for you. I'd make sure that your input loop doesn't run into issues or start with a much longer beginning array.

Comment: WOW! I ll check all  those thing that you are telling me. Ι am programming every now and then so I am not a pro. You know... Thank u!